# Issue installing linux-headers on Debian Buster

Tags: debian, apt, gcc

I'm trying to install an application, that requires linux-headers in order to be able to build it.

The issue is, that when I try to install linux headers using:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I get the following:

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-headers-4.19.0-8-amd64 : Depends: linux-compiler-gcc-8-x86 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Looks like gcc 8 is the issue, so I tried installing build-tools but they were already installed.

Turns out that gcc version is 9

```
gcc version 9.3.0 (Debian 9.3.0-11)
```

Is there a way to downgrade 9.3 to the latest 8.x version, without breaking anything and/or is there a way to install 8.x without having to remove 9.3?

Comment: What happens if you try to install 'build-essential' package ?

Comment: build-essential is already the newest version (12.8).
build-essential set to manually installed.

Comment: try to run `apt autoremove` and tell me what happens.

Comment: You don’t need to downgrade `gcc`, `gcc-8` can be installed in parallel. What happens if you try to install `gcc-8` directly? Note that a point-release came out yesterday, with a newer kernel, so you may need to upgrade and reboot before you can install the headers and related packages properly.

Comment: On the apt autoremove which I already ran, I currently get:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.


I was able to install gcc 8 with "apt-get install gcc-8 libgcc-8-dev". However, now I can't reconfigure which gcc to be used by default. 

update-alternatives --config gcc
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for gcc

Comment: Ok.. never mind on the update alternatives. I was able to install the linux headers after installing gcc-8 & libgcc-8-dev.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install gcc via:

```
apt install gcc-8 libgcc-8-dev
```

Afterwards linux-headers installed successfully.